# Change application order in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Is there a way to change the order from left-associative to right-associative, except parentheses? For example in Haskell you can write `foo $ bar b` and `foo` will be applied to a result from `bar b`.

```
let a x = x * 4;;
let b y = y + 2;;

let c = a ??? b 3;;

print_int c;;
```

Should print 20

Answer (score 6):

Sure, you can define it yourself:

```
let (@@@) f x = f x
```

Then, `a @@@ b 3` evaluates to 20. Make sure to select a starting symbol such that it is right-associative ([see here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html#@manual.kwd32)) (`$...` is left-associative)

Comment: You could just define a '$' operator like in Haskell:  let ($) f x = f x ;;

Comment: No, actually, you cannot use '$'. It works for this basic example, but not if you try `f $ g $ h x`

Answer (score 4):

You just have to define a symbol for such applications:

```
let (@@@) f x = f x ;;
```

And then

```
let f x = x * 4;;
let g y = y + 2;;
let a = f @@@ g 3;;
print_int a;;
```

does print 20.

Note that the next version of OCaml (3.13 or 4.00) will provide builtin primitives for applications that avoid creating intermediate partially applied functions:

```
external (@@@) : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b = "%apply"
external (|>) : 'a -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b = "%revapply"
```

The last one is the opposite of `%apply`:

```
print_int (3 |> g |> f);;
```

Note that you cannot use ($) as it is left-associative in the definition of the OCaml parser:

```
let ($) f x = f x ;;
let a = f $ g 3;;  (* ok ! ??? *)
let a = f $ g $ g 3;; (* ERROR -> g is not an integer,
                        because OCaml computes (f $ g) first *)
```

Comment: Why not the shorter @@ instead @@@? Is it used in the standard library already?